# How to create a dropdown menu that uses PHP to delete rows from database?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I'm currently learning PHP at my Academy and here's a thing I'm confused about. I don't know how to create a dropdown menu in PHP using HTML form to delete a row from database. Here is my code:

```
//This is index.php
    <div>
        <?php
            include('includes/delete.php');
        ?>
    <form method="POST" action="includes/delete.php">

        <select name="username">
        <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT user_name, user_lastname FROM users");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){?>
                <option>
                <?php echo $row['user_name'];?>
                <?php echo $row['user_lastname'];?>
                </option> 
            <?php }?>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
    </form>
    </div>

//This is delete.php
<?php

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "root";
    $userPassword = "";
    $dbName = "baza_podataka";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $userPassword, $dbName);

    //Checking connection
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Error: Could not connect!" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    //Deleting an user from database
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];

        if(mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username' " )){
        echo "User was deleted!";
        }else{
            echo "User could not be deleted! Please try again later.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

delete is the id of the button and will not post. You need to check for $_post['username'].

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
...

Answer (score 0):

What missing in your code is lack of `option` value inside your `select` tag. In the meanwhile, your sql code is open to sql injection attacks and you should use bind parameters. Ok, you would use the following snippet to make your code run.

```php
  <option value="<?php echo $row['user_name']?>" >
      <?php echo $row['user_name'];?>
      <?php echo $row['user_lastname'];?>
  </option>
```

Comment: Well I tried that and it didn't work, nothing happens, it just says "User could not be deleted" like I wrote on that ELSE..

Comment: Is the  `$_POST['username']` filled with data?